# boxplot ggplot python not filling boxes with colours

Tags: python, ggplot2, boxplot

So im using the diamonds dataset and want to do a box plot of price and cut of the diamond using ggplot in python. This is the line of code to do the plot.

`ggplot(aes('cut','price',fill='cut'),diamonds) +geom_boxplot()`

However, boxes stay gray even though the color legend shows. This is the plot I get:

[image: Boxplot y=price, x=cut.]

How can I make the boxes fill the colour in the legend?? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue using ggplot 0.11.5, Python3.6 under Windows 7.  Probably best to [check the open issues](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/issues) and file a new one if necessary.

Comment: In R, the boxes of this plot has colours.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue (Python 3.6, ggplot 0.11.5) in 2019